# Guide to Three.js with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js

We're beginning to learn Node.js in class, and one of our assignments is to research any given Node.js module, learn the basics, and present it to the class. While I was trying to find Node.js modules, one of the lists took me to Three.js.

I have found an exceedingly small amount of documentation or guides on using Three.js with Node.js - in fact, I've found none, and yes, I have Googled extensively. Maybe I'm just bad at Googling. That said, does anyone know of any guides, walkthroughs, or half-mad ramblings I could consult? I'm not looking to have someone solve all my problems for me (necessarily!), but I do need SOME idea of where to start.

EDIT: This is all from the perspective of a beginner, not just with Three.js but also with Node.js.

Comment: I may be way off base, but I would think that you would be better researching something more recent with active contributions.  Libraries with only 2-3 contributors and no updates in 2+ years tend to be rather specialized, and not exactly designed for widespread use... they are almost always documented in that same mindset, that the people using them likely already understand most of the internals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can get help from : https://github.com/nulltask/node-three.js, it relies on three.js npm module.

you can install it with :

Installation

> $ npm install three.js

check examples in above github link.